# .net MVC：How do I serve static files only to authorized users

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

There are static files in my website like:

> http://myurl.com/Content/a.html
>
> http://myurl.com/Content/b.html

... etc

I want to verify the user's authentication when access. The authentication should be check by database's data.

My framework：ASP.NET MVC5

Comment: Ideally it should be redirected via Controller and Action method where you can implementing Authentication & Authorization.

Comment: I've trying by this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357311/net-mvc-how-to-hide-the-true-url) , but the javascript file from static html was relative path, so when I use http://myurl.com/Content/a.html as source in my Action it will get javascript file from http://myurl.com/MyController/MyAction/abc.js, it display wrong..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved this problem by [this way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41357311/net-mvc-how-to-hide-the-true-url), a important thing is I must to replace the static file's relative path with absolute path.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure users are authenticated by using the authorization element in your web.config. If all your static pages are in a folder named StaticPages, add a web.config file to that folder and insert the code below.

```
<location path="/StaticPages">
 <system.web>
  <authorization>
    <deny users="?"/>
  </authorization>
</system.web>
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8d82143t(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This can just go in your main web.config file without the "/" in the path.

Answer (score 2):

Create web.config file in your static folder and insert this code.

```
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of putting your files in the traditional method `/myserver/myfile.html`, consider adding an action which returns the file after authinticating the user:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult GetFile(string name)
{
   // return the file
}
```

You may also use `OutputCache` attribute to cache your static file so that it is not being requested every time (if you are sure your file contents will not be changed)